# Como crear una lista de tuplas que cumplan cierta condicion

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy usando el programa Python 3.

Quiero crear una función que me devuelva una lista de tuples de números que cumplan la siguiente condición: Para unos tuples que contendrán un numero de valores, denominemos v a esos valores, y llamemosle p la potencia a la cual se va a elevar cada uno de esos valores, la condición que han de cumplir esos tuples es que v[0]**p + v[1]**p + .. + v[n-1]**p sea igual a v[n]**p.

La función debe contener 3 variables:

1. numero de elementos que tendrán los tuples,
2. potencia a la cual se elevara cada valor y
3. N que denotara que valores tendrán dichos tuples.

Pondré un ejemplo: llamemos la función tuple_satisfie_condition(20, 2, 3) y que devolverá como resultado la siguiente lista de tuples:

[(3, 4, 5), (4, 3, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 6, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 5, 13), (12, 9, 15), (12, 16, 20), (15, 8, 17), (16, 12, 20)]

como se ve 3 al cuadrado + 4 al cuadrado = 5 al cuadrado, también 5 al cuadrado + 12 al cuadrado = 13 al cuadrado, etc.

Lo único que he podido crear hasta ahora es la función condicion y gracias por la ayuda:

```
def tuples(Pow, Tuple):
    powered_tuple = [(x**Pow) for x in Tuple]
    if sum(powered_tuple[:-1]) == powered_tuple[-1]:
          return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

En la librería `itertools` existe la función `permutations`. Esta función recibe una lista y un número *n*, retornando un iterador que recorre todas las posibles combinaciones de *n* elementos de la lista. En esto el orden es importante, por lo que (2, 3) y (3, 2) son considerados dos combinaciones diferentes.

Una vez teniendo la lista de todas las permutaciones, todo se reduce a probar cuales cumplen la condición. Es una búsqueda exhaustiva, bastante ineficiente, no recomendable para datos voluminosos. Por ejemplo, `calcular(4, 2, 50)` se demora 6 segundos en mi máquina y produce una lista de 642 elementos.

```
from itertools import permutations

def calcular(elementos, potencia, ultimo):
    """ Produce lista de tuplas que cumplen condicion.

    :param elementos: Numero de elementos en cada tupla
    :param potencia: Potencia a la que elevar los elementos.
    :param ultimo: Ultimo valor de los elementos.
    :return: Lista de tuplas que cumplen la condicion
    """
    resultado = []
    numeros = range(1, ultimo+1)
    for comb in permutations(numeros, elementos):
        suma = sum([x ** potencia for x in comb[:-1]])
        if suma == comb[-1] ** potencia:
            resultado.append(comb)
    return resultado

result = calcular(3, 2, 20)
print(result)
```

produce

```
[(3, 4, 5), (4, 3, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 6, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 5, 13), (12, 9, 15), (12, 16, 20), (15, 8, 17), (16, 12, 20)]
```

Comment: muchas gracias. Solo tengo una duda. por que necesitaste crear esa lista numeros = [x for x in range(1, ultimo+1)]? No bastaba con crear lo siguiente? numeros = range(1, ultimo + 1). Muchas gracias

Comment: @Inti. Toda la razón. Edite la respuesta. Gracias